# How can a Python program background itself?

Tags: python, command-line, parallel-processing, background-process

Consider the following Python command-line program.  It doesn't work because it is incomplete, but I think it illustrates the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import multiprocessing

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
for task in expensive_iterator_with_user_interaction():
    pool.call_async(expensive_computation, (task,))
pool.close()

print("Dear user, you may now press Ctrl-Z and bg this script.")
pool.join()
```

Thus, the problem is that this scripts needs user input while it's launching expensive parallel processes.  But then there is the moment when user interaction is not needed anymore.  Then, I ask the user to background this process with shell actions.

However, can this be achieved also by the program itself?

(Side note: The core of the problem is the entanglement of user input with firing the “expensive computations”.  Therefore, I cannot separate both in two scripts, and letting one spawning the other as a daemon.)

Comment: check this function https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork

Comment: Does this work in a multiprocessing-using script, too?  How about open files and open pipes to subprocesses?

Comment: I am not sure if it does but should work in my opinion

Answer (score -1):

The command `screen` may help you.

Use `screen -L` to create a new session and run you application. After inputting some data, you can press "*Ctrl-A*" and then press "*D*" on your keyboard to detach the session.

Now, your application is running in the background.

If you want to do some other things or input more data, you can use command `screen -r` to reattach to the previous session.

`screen` is just like a virtual screen, so you can switch your program to the background or foreground according to your needs.

Comment: Yes but this is not user-friendly.  After all, Ctrl+Z+bg works, too.  But both needs additional action of the user.  The program is to be published and should be as easy to use as possible.